# SSIS Script task hangs during debugging, when breakpoint is removed and saved

Tags: debugging, ssis

[image]I am using SSIS 2012. I have a script task in which I am looping through a set of rows in c#. I have a breakpoint in my code & I only want the program to stop on it once.

So here are the steps:

1. I execute the package - the script task launches as one
   would expect. The control is stopped at the breakpoint that I had
   created. It is highlighted in yellow.
2. At this point, I
   check some values and I do not want the program to stop  again, so I
   delete the breakpoint and click on the Save button.

The Visual studio hangs/freezes at that point. I have waited for 10 mins after which I force-closed it.

Comment: Option 1) there is a message box hiding elsewhere on the screen waiting for you to click OK. Option 2) Don't delete the breakpoints & save the project. Instead, click the Disable Breakpoints button. Option 3) stop interacting with the UI. Instead use `FireInformation` events, similar to your FireError. Option 4) isn't your FireError event going to cause the data flow to error out?

Comment: Options 1 - there is  no box. Opt 2. disable breakpoint state is not saved. So in the next for loop iteration of ssis task  when it opens the script task, it  enables the breakpoint that i disabled earlier. Option 3. it does not apply to debugging. Isnt it more of an error handling mechanism. Option 4. It will.. but lets say there is not error and I have a breakpoint in the try loop that i want to disable after checking the data in the first iteration.. thanks for your help

Comment: You're breaking inside an exception. It's possible the exception itself is causing a stability issue. Regardless I don't recommend using SSIS for its C# debugging features.

Comment: also.... what happens if you don't delete the breakpoint? Does it still freeze or does it behave normally (breaks again). I know you said there is no hidden msgbox, but did you check in task manager?